# How to Disable ToolTip without Removing the "title" attribute [ASP.NET]

Tags: attributes, tooltip, title, watermark

I have 3 TextBoxes

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" class="txtFields" title="Title" />

<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" class="txtFields" title="Name" />

<asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" class="txtFields" title="Description" />
```

I'm using the watermark plugin on these 3 TextBoxes:

```
jQuery('.txtFields').watermark();
```

This is the plugin:
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/

jQuery('.txtFields').watermark();
Uses the Title Attribute of the TextBox to Show the Watermark but the problem is that this also Generates ToolTips which is something I do Not want, is there anyway to disable the tooltips without removing the title attribute?
Or is there anyway to use custom attributes with this plugin? By that I mean making the plugin use another attribute instead of the title attribute.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like watermark will allow you to specify any text to display in there, so you're not stuck with the title.  Any attribute that you could select with jQuery you could use as the watermark value.  The problem with that is there are no other attributes you could add in there and still have nice compliant code.  Best bet is to give them a value, assign a variable that value, unset it and add watermark. Something like:

```
$('input').each(function() {
  var wmark = $(this).val();
  $(this).val('');
  $(this).watermark(wmark);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding UseAccessibleHeader = false

like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" class="txtFields" title="Title" UseAccessibleHeader = false />
```